# What is the difference between "exclusively depends" and "only depends"?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

What is the difference when someone says that

an expression  exclusively depends on $x$

and

an expression only depends $x$?

Comment: No difference at all, I would say. Do you have any examples?

Comment: @TonyK, consider the example in this image http://i.imgur.com/4G6Tbki.png

Comment: Then yes, they mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They almost certainly mean the same thing.

But "$y$ only depends on $x$" is probably not what the writer meant. He (or she) probably meant "$y$ depends only on $x$".

What's the difference? Well, "$y$ depends only on $x$" means that $y$ depends on $x$ and doesn't depend on anything else. This is the same as "$y$ depends exclusively on $x$".

On the other hand, "$y$ only depends on $x$" has a slightly different meaning. It means that $y$ depends on $x$, and there is no other relationship (besides this dependence) between $y$ and $x$. In other words, the dependence is the only relationship that exists.

It's probably safe to assume that the writer just put his "only" in the wrong place. This is a common practice, and many people would not even consider it to be wrong.

Comment: Why does the author in this example use the two expressions http://i.imgur.com/4G6Tbki.png ?

Comment: For variety. The English language is very rich, and there are often several ways of saying the same thing. This is nice. It means we can avoid boring repetition. But it can be very confusing for people whose native language is not English. It's natural to assume that different words have different meanings, but often this is not the case.